# What medium does 50Mb limit for Web SQL Database on iOS apply to?

Tags: ios, web-sql

I have been researching this topic for a while but have come across no specific answers.  I am attempting to insert a set of videos into a Web SQL Database on a site I'm developing.  The issue I have is the videos that memory amounts to 300Mb+ and the cache limit for iOS is 50Mb.  What does this 50Mb limit apply to, is it: the domain, the browser or the device?  If it's the domain, a workaround (this is only for investigation purposes) could be to download 50Mb of video data to the DB, go to a different domain, then download 50Mb etc.  If it's the device or browser then I'm stuck on 50Mb.

Any answers would be good for my investigation.

** EDIT **
*I have minus points but can I stress again this is purely for investigation, R&D!*

Thanks

Chris

Comment: What are you referring to when you say 'the limit for iOS is 50Mb?' What limit? Where did you hear that? Are you referring to the maximum size an app can be while downloading from the AppStore over a cellular connection?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Acey, the 50Mb is the cache limit, so a web SQL DB, IndexedDB, or Application Cache cannot be over 50Mb.  The following resource demonstrates this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 50Mb is restricted to the domain, so you could in theory visit different domains to download 50Mb on each.